# Calibre database corrupted message. What can I do to fix it?

Tags: database, calibre

Love Calibre but cant open it...

Trying to open.....Calibre, version 3.7.0

I get the following message

```
Corrupted database: The library database at C:\Users\......\Calibre Library appears to be corrupted. Do you want calibre to try and rebuild it automatically? The rebuild may not be completely successful. If you say No, a new empty calibre library will be created.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\calibre\gui2\main.py", line 303, in initialize_db
File "site-packages\calibre\db\legacy.py", line 81, in __init__
File "site-packages\calibre\db\legacy.py", line 48, in create_backend
File "site-packages\calibre\db\backend.py", line 384, in __init__
File "site-packages\calibre\db\schema_upgrades.py", line 19, in __init__
File "site-packages\calibre\db\backend.py", line 843, in execute
File "c:\t\t\apsw-9hooel\apsw-3.13.0-r1\src\cursor.c", line 236, in resetcursor
ReadOnlyError: ReadOnlyError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

I am running Windows 10....the folders are always default 'Read Only'...and are not changeable in folder properties - attributes...system permissions means this is not a problem...it 'applies' but does not does not save with 'read only' attribute unchecked...

I have tried option "yes" but that does not succeed
I have tried option 'No" but fails to create a new database ...get message below

```
calibre, version 3.7.0
ERROR: Bad database location: Bad database location u'C:\\Users\\Robyn\\Desktop\\Kindle Library\\Calibre Library rebuild'. calibre will now quit.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\calibre\gui2\main.py", line 284, in initialize_db_stage2
File "site-packages\calibre\db\legacy.py", line 81, in __init__
File "site-packages\calibre\db\legacy.py", line 48, in create_backend
File "site-packages\calibre\db\backend.py", line 377, in __init__
File "site-packages\calibre\db\backend.py", line 1121, in fget
File "site-packages\calibre\db\backend.py", line 834, in conn
File "site-packages\calibre\db\backend.py", line 266, in __init__
CantOpenError: CantOpenError: unable to open database file
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Calibre software

I have restored the database using the command prompt from Windows powershell (option 'yes") this appeared to be successful... but the database
created does not open.

In Windows 10 I have Restored the database from a back up... known working point pre problem ...no go..same messages

I already have excluded the database and Calibre from Anti-virus
scanning...I am using.Bitdefender total Security 2017

---

I did contact the bug guys at Calibre... got the reply below...I think they did not even read my email as I said that I had already tried their suggestions.... and not running dropbox...or new software.....but they did suggest posting here!!

> Something on your computer is preventing calibre from opening the
> database file (the metadata.db file in the calibre library folder).
> The most common culprits are:
>
> 1. Anti-virus programs 2) File permissions 3) Some sync software tlike
>    DropBox that accesses files in the calibre library folder at the same
>    time as calibre.
>
> You will need to figure out what it is on your computer that is
> blocking calibre. If you need help doing that, you can post in the
> calibre forums at mobileread.com. Start by disabling your antivirus
> program.

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu ?

Comment: Also read the last part of that email "If you need help doing that, you can post in the calibre forums at mobileread.com"  - https://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=166

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem, I reinstalled the latest version of calibre and that fixed it right up. If that doesn't work try going back to the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this can happen for for other reasons, but in my case it was Bitdefender and it's "Protected folders" that caused this. Whitelisting calibre in Bitdefender solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently turned on ransomware protection in Windows 10. It turns out that was blocking calibre.exe. You can find this by going into Windows Security and looking at the ransomware settings. Once I unblocked it Calibre is working again.